# I can't connect SQL Server on VS Code

Tags: sql-server, vscode-extensions

I installed SQL Server extension on VSCode and tried to connect SQL Server so much but failed.

1. hostname/instance: correct (not localhost)
2. database name: not specify
3. user name: 'john'
4. password: '...'
5. Save password? Yes
6. profile name: not specify

I tried 1 ~ 6 course around 30 times but kept saying that error.

Error: "mssql: Error: Login failed. Retry using different credentials?"
Please help me!

Comment: thiose ports are closed for a good reason, so you must change the datavase rules to allllow access

Comment: The authentication error passed to the client is intentionally vague. You need to check the SQL Server's logs to find out the true authentication error. If you aren't the DBA, then I suggest you speak to them.

Comment: I did set the rules to access already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. Add new user id and password

- Open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and connect to the SQL Server instance.
- Expand the "Security" folder in the Object Explorer.
- Right-click on the "Logins" folder and select "New Login..."
- In the "Login - New" window, enter "..." as the login name.
- Select the "SQL Server authentication" option and enter a new password in the "Password" field.
- Uncheck the "Enforce password policy" and "Enforce password expiration" options.
- Click on the "Server Roles" tab and make sure the "sysadmin" role is selected.
- Click on the "OK" button to create the login with the new password.

2. Get hostname and instance name

- Open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).
- Connect to the SQL Server instance you want to retrieve the hostname and instance information for.
- Once connected, right-click on the server instance in the Object Explorer window.
- Select "Properties" from the context menu.
- In the Server Properties window, navigate to the "General" tab.
- Look for the "Name" field, which will display the full name(hostname \instance) of the SQL Server.

3. Check if the new user id and password are working fine.

- Open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).
- Connect to the SQL Server with new user id and password you created.
  Choose SQL Server Authentication instead of Windows Authentication

4. If it is connected on SSMS, you can try with the hostname/instance, user id and password on VS Code.
5. If failed on VS Code, remove the SQL Server extension and install it again.
   When you install the extension, don't close vscode editor till necessary files are completely downloaded.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: This worked for me! 5th - Reinstall the extension. It was problem. Thank you!